# What is PPXSZN in PDF char details. for example. <type 'list'>: ['PPXSZN', 'Arial,Bold']

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, pdfminer

Pdf uses : ['PPXSZN', 'Arial,Bold'] kind of array to store char font details. Here What is this **PPXSZN** stands for? I use pdf miner to extract this.

Comment: Looks like a prefix for embedded font subsets